# MYSQL Почему нельзя использовать псевдонимы таблиц в подзапросах формруя выражения удаления?

Tags: mysql, sql

Строчка из книги Алана Бьюли "Изучаем sql":

При использовании связанных подзапросов в выражениях `delete`
в MySQL необходимо помнить, что псевдонимы таблиц не допускаются
ни в коем случае.

Рабочий пример:

```
DELETE FROM department
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM employee
                  WHERE employee.dept_id = department.dept_id);
```

Нерабочий пример:

```
DELETE FROM department d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM employee e
                  WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id);
```

Почему ?

Comment: кому там не понятна суть вопроса, интересно?

Comment: Покажите конкретный пример такого запроса. Может, просто не там используете псевдонимы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подзапросы здесь совершенно ни при чём. Имеет значение здесь сам [синтаксис `delete`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
[PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

`FROM tbl_name` - по синтаксису здесь алиасов нет, это не `table_reference`, необходимо именно имя самой таблицы. Потому запрос и возвращает синтаксическую ошибку. Так сделан парсер в mysql, скорей всего специально, но подробностей не знаю.

Но алиасы таблиц можно использовать в многотабличных запросах `Multiple-Table Syntax`, в том числе в вырожденном случае удаления из только одной таблицы:

```
DELETE d FROM department d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM employee e
                  WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id);
```

Этот запрос уже корректен, но в DELETE указывать необходимо именно алиас таблицы. `DELETE department FROM department d` будет уже некорректен.